# Guests(live account) added to Azure AD are not able to login if tenant id is passed during o-Auth flow in a B2B scenario

Tags: adal, office365api

We are having Azure AD B2B integration, where a live id account is added to a Office 365 Tenant.

When initiating o-auth flow if we specify tenant Id its not working for these guests users only it works fine for regular users in that tenant.

Initial o-auth flow request with tenant Id which fails for the same user.

[https://login.microsoftonline.com/c7105dda-a548-4def-8ee7-e992e0e6dcb0/oauth2/authorize?client_id=.....](https://login.microsoftonline.com/c7105dda-a548-4def-8ee7-e992e0e6dcb0/oauth2/authorize?client_id=%3CClientID%3E&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44349%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=code%20id_token&scope=openid%20profile&response_mode=form_post&nonce=637505268863366814.NGIzNDlkNmUtNDE0Mi00ZmM5LWE1MjMtNDJmZTUwMzMxMjU4YWQ3ZTQ5YTItMjAzZS00ZjA0LTgyMjEtZDgwZTRmYmE0MDQz&domain_hint=figg.onmicrosoft.com&state=CfDJ8AmIwUTtfIRKmiJxVBYIakWifGVqwnP3VpGTBqp-uSv8qJ9T6WAh9GIuoHlMImbFEcibNio33A7zBAaF-G5mF6o_JrObRKzF_pOSYukXWF76AhGtyfWtHzgo4oYZmnwlwGRJiF9QLP964ShDXPrHRoilGubFOH-EHYDh8pshSXwEMkz5Bkosf6tWSk8CI5QSXBLL4Xs78noO0s17e687ZGpRpePzhoWKxNbnGvhGbwh9_OlJeNAHPsvy04bF8rGD0kHKrrBZ8tknR4ebDNlTnEpTHwz47YIBSNuclSCi-MOiPI8VIBo0JsyD3IYn0cS-0xWEdyh6Ng-D46HBjRzYkT1yT535Hw6waCLAWmPs4QiHAdVy21xn5kt0rB2nJKYFiWgWLAlaTdAh9oq4RLU6IRV7njf72wfNrRBlL_5WfxgxvCV2RUWhlBJhZpkXhZA6g6wnqJgobyDaw7wCbttbBGOB6Epr6VBxQgrsnMtk3-EacAI1eSk0HrTxkBDPyzW17ZOZGEXRFyxb9X79kSlJQMsOUp3uJ_tpMcpUmMORlsQ5dy8UzHsiUrPFP95Iu1rjV0gFuQlkVSWG6MBUfipuWf0iS2TrJMYZWtnjXrthSIik9GFJC6a7mHRgtd5210PK5PlgVQE3Sh2kK2zDF__BJv_t2hQknHzcyIdclBJm6YBrn_DAi32MPAPcmkHH84g7T06WnRQL9ShAFmzhho1Z-_4bntZ-KCqBhczgz905R_fs8DIDh788WxIAPwiK6qTMHE5EhLdDVEE2-rrAgtITfgIa9kLilNdKIbz1bpKeN67GCCIgDbR-4d0vOx1RsXEp0pMw12tLqtFf5DgMKX09pEWjj1gA6YyH1cb1cIo15Jaw&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0&x-client-ver=5.3.0.0)

However for same tenant and same user if we don't pass the tenant Id it works fine.

[https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=...](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=%3CClientId%3E&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44349%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=code%20id_token&scope=openid%20profile&response_mode=form_post&nonce=637505274276407222.NGIyNGZiMzItNmU3YS00YWNhLWI0MGYtZjM3N2NiNjNlNzUyYzQ4ZWFmMjgtZmZkNi00MjUzLWJmOGYtZjU2Y2FkZThkZjM3&state=CfDJ8AmIwUTtfIRKmiJxVBYIakXDHn47C6MB0QV1aAZrRkifxM51hUeejmGwy6CN1_p1SUT-M5-OAMXmAJlXTWAnoRRW95FvI9cP2bSAtkALBwjXD2ahPMtVrPfm0dzvvKXmxqDH40fcnjc9zoJNHG7pyBqat3MlQGbrbeEQW2loX7Quyf7F4q5JNFHR2G7GgIRmNTzEPpss5HE5VFTtfWCsB03VNLE0f7lMm6G19qLAfdu5aA9XMd9F-9Gn9u27gYT20kcPRx3iyIMtMNexosKhewYJf8PSKD0V-A0ilWFqv9l78C7JO2Ktj53pe1Xt7ks6-9THMdsz6YAjkv0aqA1aF14mhVa5AQrLwQgZo5a8x7HylMrVtUrs9dCwid03_L8XfDPywWDw5ro3qy5UZzOmtUBErAW8wkyr1ezqtobjrV0PrMpTQ_4TxiBIyKshuhRN79BDcChrAQcRxtEitEn-9R7558eyzOgi7ig8AhCRdtnM&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0&x-client-ver=5.3.0.0)

We get the following error if tenant id is passed. full error details can be found in the image below.

```
This login.live.com page can’t be foundNo webpage was found for the web address: https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?response_type=code&client_id=51483342-085c-4d86-bf88-cf50c7252078&scope=openid+profile+email+offline_access
```

[image]

Comment: I guess this may be related to the url, try to use the url：```https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=8b281d88-a0b2-406e-ac4e-c26e3a39fxxx
&response_type=code
&scope=user.read
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&state=12345```

Comment: Thanks @Deepak and endpoint configuration will help. Please follow this document - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-client-application-configuration